# Gtkmm error with linking step

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, gtkmm, linker-errors

Today i have tried to write a simple HelloWorld program
in c++ using gtkmm library. When i tried to compile using:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0` main.cc  -o main
```

the linker show me this:

```
/tmp/ccY4sTsR.o: nella funzione "main":
main.cc:(.text+0x36): undefined reference "Gtk::Main::Main(int&, char**&, bool)"
main.cc:(.text+0x50):undefined reference to"Gtk::Window::Window(Gtk::WindowType)"
main.cc:(.text+0x65): undefined reference  "Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)"
main.cc:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to "Gtk::Window::set_title(Glib::ustring const&)"
main.cc:(.text+0x84): undefined reference  to"Glib::ustring::~ustring()"
main.cc:(.text+0x97): undefined reference  to"Gtk::Main::run(Gtk::Window&)"
main.cc:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference  to "Gtk::Main::~Main()"
main.cc:(.text+0xda): reference not defined to "Glib::ustring::~ustring()"
main.cc:(.text+0xeb): reference not defined to "Gtk::Main::~Main()"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

so i checked if the libgtkmm-2.0 was installed using:

```
dpkg -l|grep gtkmm
```

and it showed me:

```
ii  gtkmm-documentation                                         3.18.0-1                                                    all          Documentation of C++ wrappers for GLib/GTK+
ri  libgtkmm-2.4-1v5:amd64                                      1:2.24.4-2                                                  amd64        C++ wrappers for GTK+ (shared libraries)
ii  libgtkmm-2.4-dbg:amd64                                      1:2.24.4-2                                                  amd64        C++ wrappers for GTK+ (debug symbols)
ii  libgtkmm-2.4-dev:amd64                                      1:2.24.4-2                                                  amd64        C++ wrappers for GTK+ (development files)
ii  libgtkmm-2.4-doc                                            1:2.24.4-2                                                  all          C++ wrappers for GTK+ (documentation)
ri  libgtkmm-3.0-1v5:amd64                                      3.18.0-1                                                    amd64        C++ wrappers for GTK+ (shared libraries)
ii  libgtkmm-3.0-dbg:amd64                                      3.18.0-1                                                    amd64        C++ wrappers for GTK+ (debug symbols)
ii  libgtkmm-3.0-dev:amd64                                      3.18.0-1                                                    amd64        C++ wrappers for GTK+ (development files)
ii  libgtkmm-3.0-doc                                            3.18.0-1                                                    all          C++ wrappers for GTK+ (documentation)
```

the code of main.cc file is:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/main.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);


    Gtk::Window* main_win = new Gtk::Window (Gtk::WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    main_win->set_title ("prove");


    if (main_win)
    {
        kit.run(*main_win);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

can anyone help me??

Comment: what does `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0` return? You have to put some lib option after the link target.

Comment: You can try to compile with `g++ main.cc 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0' -o main`. For the needs of the link edition, the libraries should know the dependencies they have to solve. So usually main.cc should occur before the libraries in the compilation line.

Comment: @Franck thanks it works. I was really stupid.  Sorry for the lose of times